# Spark build failed

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, spark-hive

I have downloaded the spark source from apache site, then I built the source using maven.

```
spark - version 1.6.3
hadoop - version 2.7.3
scala - version 2.10.4
```

I have used below command for build the project

```
 .build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.7 -Dhadoop.version=2.7.3 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -Dscala-2.10 -DskipTests clean package
```

I have tried with version - Phadoop-2.4, 2.6 but every time I am getting error at the time of hive build --

> Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project spark-hive_2.10: wrap: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found. -> [Help 1]

[image]

Comment: Similar issue here ever figure it out?